# Elixir - Order by using table associations

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to do a query that fetches the `user_posts` table and the respective associations `upvotes`, `downvotes` and `comments`. And I tried like this:

```
popular_posts =
  from(s in UserPost, 
    where: s.inserted_at >= ^Timex.beginning_of_month(Timex.now()),
    where: s.inserted_at <= ^Timex.end_of_month(Timex.now()),
    left_join: downvotes in assoc(s, :downvotes),
    left_join: comments in assoc(s, :comments), 
    left_join: upvotes in assoc(s, :upvotes),
    preload: [comments: comments, upvotes: upvotes, downvotes: downvotes],
    order_by: fragment("(? * 0.5) + (? * 0.1) - (? * 0.4)", ^map_size(s.upvotes), ^map_size(s.comments), ^map_size(s.downvotes)))
  |> Repo.all
```

But it gives the following warnings and errors:

```
warning: variable "s" does not exist and is being expanded to "s()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
  lib/nethub_api_web/resolvers/content.ex:33

warning: variable "s" does not exist and is being expanded to "s()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
  lib/nethub_api_web/resolvers/content.ex:33

warning: variable "args" is unused
  lib/nethub_api_web/resolvers/content.ex:93


== Compilation error in file lib/nethub_api_web/resolvers/content.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/nethub_api_web/resolvers/content.ex:33: undefined function s/0
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:198: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

I tried with changing `s` with `UserPosts` but it says that the columns don't exist in the table.

Comment: I have a feeling that you are confusing `Ecto`. How about ditching the `left_join` and construct the `join` with `on` and show the path to `Ecto`

Comment: If I change in with join it's the same.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you remove the `preload`?

Comment: Yeah the same issue.

Comment: ok. Here how I would do. I would by pass the `schema` and directly `from( s in "user_posts ....`, which it means adjusting your `from`. Next I would remove all of the `joins` and add them one at a time to see which one breaks

Comment: I have had a similar issue. In my case, I was confusing the Ecto with `left_joins` so I removed them and used `join` and `on` and everything was fine.

Comment: Lastly why are you doing `where: s.inserted_at >= ^Timex.beginning_of_month(Timex.now()),
    where: s.inserted_at <= ^Timex.end_of_month(Timex.now()),` ? do you want to do `OR` ? if yes then use `or_where` - https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#or_where/3

Comment: I'm trying to do an `AND` and can you explain how to use `join` and `on`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172725/discussion-between-mr-h-and-diego-francisco).

Comment: I did that and I get `undefined function comments/0` and similar with the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why, but when I changed:

```
preload: [comments: comments, upvotes: upvotes, downvotes: downvotes],
order_by: fragment("(? * 0.5) + (? * 0.1) - (? * 0.4)", 
^map_size(s.upvotes), ^map_size(s.comments), ^map_size(s.downvotes)))
```

to:

```
preload: [:comments, :upvotes, :downvotes],
order_by: fragment("(? * 0.5) + (? * 0.1) - (? * 0.4)", 
^map_size(:upvotes), ^map_size(:comments), ^map_size(:downvotes)))
```

It worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

convert `left_join` to `join` with `on`

Here is an example from `Ecto` Doc:

```
 from c in Comment,
  join: p in Post, on: p.id == c.post_id,
  select: {p.title, c.text}
```

Reference:
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#join/5

When I have lots of `join`, I prefer to use `join` and `on` so I don't confuse Ecto.

Also move the `where` after the `join`, not really important however an old saying in RDBMS. Join before Where.

In your `Where` clause, instead of second `where` use `and`. ( again better to do this in one `Ecto.Query` as you are not breaking things into bits.

---

Now if none of the above solved your issue, then bypass the `Schema` and replace the `UserPost` with `"user_posts"` and construct all of the joins manually. then 
use `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.to_sql(:all, Repo, query)` where `query` is your `from` result then run the generated SQL directly on your DB and check the errors there, you can adjust your query there and translate it back to `Ecto`.

---

Now if still you have issue, start removing your Joins one by one directly from DB to see what is broken.

---

My suggestion:

- Remove all of the `join` and `Schema` out of the query
- Follow: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#join/5
- Write a Raw sql and ignore `Ecto`
- Run your SQL directly on DB **OR**
- Run the SQL directly with `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(Repo, query, [params1, params2])`
- Then translate it into Ecto

Comment: I changed them to something like this: `join: upvotes in Upvote, on: upvotes.id == s.upvotes` and in `order_by` I get `undefined function s/0`.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying if you remove `order_by` you get the result, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah I get the result but not ordered like I want.

Comment: Yeah, I can't manage to get the posts ordered as I want still.

Comment: So if you can't get result with Raw SQL, Ecto can't do it Either. `Ecto.Query` is just like SQL. It is similar to `LINKQ`.